# Hide URL Parameters from URL Angular JS + Flex

Tags: java, angularjs, flex3

We have a legacy application which was developed in Adobe Flex/Java. We have another application being developed in Angular JS. Requirement is to redirect the user from Angular JS app to Flex app. So, we have decided to just do a POST request to Flex app along with passing the parameters in URL. Flex app requires few parameters, like login user details, to login to Flex application. So, When Angular JS redirects the user to Flex app using $location we are also appending the URL with required login user details. However, the problem, I see is , all these values are appearing in browser's URL which is not acceptable to the end user.

My Question is
1) What is the best way to redirect from Angular JS app to Flex app along with passing parameters and not to be visible to users on Browser's URL.
2) If whatever described above is correct, can you please suggest us on how to hide query parameters in browser window ? Can that be handled in Angular JS or do I have to make some changes in Flex app.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

There are two more methods to use.

1) Pass parameters to your swf via html embed and read it in swf on load (using FlashVars):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html

2) Write login data to browser cookies and read it in swf (using calls to JavaScript in your page via ExternalInterface)

Also please refer to Accessing browser cookies from Flex

[Accessing browser cookies from Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523633/accessing-browser-cookies-from-flex)

Original Question: 
[html form post to flex app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207880/html-form-post-to-flex-app)